# Example of reciprocal equation of type II of even degree

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, roots

A reciprocal equation is an equation in which, if x is replaced by 1/x,  the same equation is obtained. Let us take a polynomial equation of degree 4

$$a_0x^4+a_1x^3+a_2x^2+a_3x^4+a_4=0$$

where $a_0$, $a_1$, $a_2$, $a_3$ and $a_4$ are constants/coefficients.

There are four types. Type I is a type of equation which is of even degree and has coefficients a0 and a4 equal and same sign. Type II is a type of equation which has the coefficients a0 and a1 equal in magnitude but opposite in sign.

For example,

$x^3-px^2+px-1=0$ is an equation of type II of odd degree.

> Is $x^4-px^3+px-1=0$ an equation of type II of even degree?

I wonder, what would be the equation of type II of degree $4$ in the above case if coefficient of $x^2$ is also non-zero.

Comment: Yes, and for even degree the middle coefficient doesn't really matter when solving – it just changes the constant term of the folded equation.

Comment: By the definition as-written the central term (in $x^2$ in this case) has to be $0$ since the coefficient must equal its own opposite.

Answer (score 1):

There are four types of reciprocal equation $f(x)=0:$

i) Type 1 - for even degree (in this case of degree 4) and $a_0$ and $a_4$ are same sign. Therefore the solution is to divide the equation by $x^2$ for degree $4$. For equation having degree 6 as the highest degree, we have to divide by $x^3$.

ii) Type 2 - for polynomial equation (degree 4 or degree 6), if $a_0$ and $a_4$ are equal but have opposite sign, then $x=1$ and $x=-1$ are two of the roots

iii) Type $3$: For odd degree( highest power of the equation 3 or 5) if $a_0$ and $a_4$ are same sign and equal, $x=-1$ is one of the root

iv) Type 4: For odd degree, a0 and a4 are equal in magnitude but opposite in sign , x=1 is one of the root.

So, when you say,
$x^3-px^2+px-1=0$ is an equation of type II of odd degree, it falls into Type 4 for me and when you say, $$a_0x^4+a_1x^3+a_2x^2+a_3x^4+a_4=0$$, the equation looks incorrect as a0 and a3 correspond to the same power.

I used university book as my reference material. Kindly please mark the answer as correct, if it answers your question or kindly further edit it.